# Woocommerce Tax Setting according to tax-id and country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to calculate tax in woocommerce according to following conditions.

1. If person is from Germany, then he has to pay 19% tax
2. If person is out of Germany and do not have tax id number, then also he has to pay 19% tax
3. If person is out Germany but he has valid tax id number, in that case he need not to pay any tax.

Thank you in advance.Please Help me.

Comment: you need a programmer...

Comment: I am a wordpress programmer.

Comment: ok.. so what have you tried so far? your question is near to off topic in SO in my opinion and will most likely be closed. You have to provide something where you are stuck...

Comment: Actually, I am confused, and dont understand where to start. Can you please guide my step by step or send me any link?

Comment: @Suraj You should probably hire a programmer or co-worker then.

Comment: A wordpress programmer will know where to start ;) [a simple google lead me here](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/202203989-Apply-different-tax-rates-based-on-the-customer-role). this will able you to change tax class... fill in your logic and you'll get there...

Comment: Currently i am at very critical condition, Please tell me any suitable way.

Comment: your #1 and #2 are just the same.. the only real question here is #3

Comment: how do you even check a  valid tax id number?

Comment: I will check with "checksum" formula.

Comment: Thank you for help @Reigel.